# Having trouble redirecting URL when query string is present in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I updated my website, and I'm attempting to make sure a bunch of old URLs redirect to the correct page. Some of my links are working fine, while others aren't.

Example:

```
Redirect 301 /compare-suites/ /en/our-products/compare-suites
Redirect 301 /compare-suites/?lang=fr /fr/nos-produits/comparaison-des-suites/
```

The first redirect works perfectly, but the second one redirects to `/en/our-products/compare-suites?lang=fr`, ignoring my second rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias module which offers the `Redirect` directive is unable to handle the query string inside a URL. That is clearly stated in the documentation. Along with the hint to use the rewriting module instead.

I *strongly* recommend that you start reading the documentation of the utilities you use:

- Alias module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html
- Rewrite Module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

As typical for OpenSource they are of excellent quality and come with great examples.

---

This would be the approach you are probably looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=fr(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?compare-suites/?$ /fr/nos-produits/comparaison-des-suites/ [QSD,R=301,END]

RewriteRule ^/?compare-suites/?$ /en/our-products/compare-suites [R=301,END]
```

Note that the more specialized exception has to be implemented *before* the more general fallback, so further up in the configuration file.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).